# Ambiguous method call with Action<T> parameter overload

Tags: c#, ambiguity, overload-resolution

I encountered some unexpected compiler behaviour when calling overloaded method with different `Action<T>` variations.

Let's say I have this class `Test` and I'm creating its instance in the `CallTest` constructor.

```
public class Test
{
    public Test(Action<long> arg)
    {

    }

    public Test(Action<decimal> arg)
    {

    }
}

public class CallTest
{
    public CallTest()
    {
        Test t = new Test(TestDecimal);
    }

    public void TestDecimal(decimal arg)
    {

    }

    public void TestLong(long arg)
    {

    }    
}
```

When calling the `Test` constructor with either `TestDecimal` or `TestLong` as a parameter I'm receiving the following error:

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: '`Test(System.Action<long>)`' and '`Test(System.Action<decimal>)`'

My guess is there's some implicit conversion going on between `long` and `decimal`, but does anyone have any other idea what could have I done wrong? Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you pass `TestDecimal` or `TestLong` as a parameter you're in fact passing a *method group* (after all, there could be more than one `TestDecimal` method - it could have been overloaded). So in both cases implicit conversion occurs - from a *method group* to a particular *delegate type*. Both methods are thus *applicable candidates* ([Section 7.4.2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691336%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)). From *applicable candidates* the overload resolution algorithm tries to find the *best* candidate. However, the rules of comparing conversions when matching parameter lists state, that if for both candidates implicit conversion occurs neither of them is *better*:

[Section 7.4.2.3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691339%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

> [...]
>
> Otherwise, neither conversion is better.

That's why in your case there is an ambiguity.

---

The workaround is of course to first cast the parameter explicitly:

```
new Test(new Action<decimal>(TestDecimal))
```

This way for one case there will be no need for implicit conversion during overload resolution (as after the cast `Action<T>` type will match exactly), and the other would have to be converted (`Action<long>` to `Action<decimal>`), and the section mentioned above states that:

> [...]
>
> If S is T1, C1 is the better conversion.
>
> If S is T2, C2 is the better conversion.
>
> [...]

Answer (score 1):

This is due to an implicit casting between long and decimal.

Here's a table of implicit castings(for simple types) in C#([Picture Source](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/dont-sweat-c-type-conversions/)):
[image]

Read more about type conversions [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/dont-sweat-c-type-conversions/).

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround:

```
    Test t = new Test(new Action<decimal>(TestDecimal));
```